# How to ensure specific shared logic is fired before anything else in an MVC web app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3

I currently have a partial view that is called within my _Layout.cshtml, and is rendered throughout my whole MVC web application. It's the first item at the top of the page to be rendered, and within the ActionResult method that is responsible for it, I have a call to my service to perform some business logic.

I originally put this service call in this particular ActionResult method as, still being new to MVC, I was falsely under the impression that it would get fired BEFORE any of the main page content, for each page across the site. However, I've just realised that the main view method is being called first, and this ChildActionOnly Method (for the Partial View) is being called afterwards.

Basically, it's essential that the business logic call that Im currently making within the ChildActionOnly Method (associated with my partial view) is made BEFORE any other page processing is carried out (as I need to perform some DB updates upon each page load, which are then reflected in each requested page).

I'm happy to split this business logic out from the current partial views actionmethod, but am unsure where it should be going, or how I should be ensuring that it's called before anything else, for each page request? What would be the norm approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a global action filter (luckily available starting MVC3).

See an example here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/08/15/asp-net-mvc-3-global-action-filters.aspx

Copying from the sample (with slight modifications):

```
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        // Your logic can come here 

        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);

        // Your logic can come here 
    }
}
```

Applying in global.asax.cs (from the article):

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    // Register global filter
    GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new MyActionFilterAttribute());

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Comment: Thanks - This looks good. Just one remaining question. When I just ran my code, it hit the OnActionExecuting method several times before the page rendered, but I only want my logic (that appears inside that routine) to be fired 'once' per page load (otherwise Ill be hitting the DB multiple times unnecessarily). What would be the best way to ensure that my logic inside this routine is only fired once per page load?

Comment: hmm... Yeah, I agree, this one executes for each action, so, if you have partial actions it executes multiple times. You can overcome this by adding something to the `HttpContext.Current.Items` collection (And check if it exists, the collection lives per single request).

Comment: Another alternative might be writing an HTTP module, this one runs really really early in ASP.NET pipeline, and runs only once

Comment: The HttpContext.Current.Items approach sounds good. I'll go for that I think. The only remaining issue I've just noticed is that the Dependency/Constructor Injection in this Attribute class is not resolving as it does in my controllers (I need to call logic in my service class => repository). Is there any reason why my autofac dependency injection should fail in this attribute class?

Comment: Similar to controllers, you may need to intercept how ASP.NET MVC instantiates/resolves the action filters. Check out this example on how to do it: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/05/03/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-filters/

Answer (score 1):

How about overriding the `OnResultExecuting` method of your controllers?  If you've got a controller base class do it in there - otherwise inject derive a new `Controller` class and make all your existing controllers inherit from that (this is good practise anyway).

```
public class MyControllerBase : Controller
{
  protected override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
    //filterContext contains the Result (e.g. ViewResult) plus route data etc.
    //you can also analyse Model and ViewData in here too.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing sounds like an [aspect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) of your application. For this MVC has a feature called [Action Filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410209.aspx).

You could implement an ActionFilterAttribute like this:

```
public class LogActionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private ILog _log = new SomeLogger();

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var type = filterContext.Controller.GetType();
        _log.Debug("Executing action '{0}' on controller '{1}'", filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName, type.Name);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var type = filterContext.Controller.GetType();
        _log.Debug("Executed action '{0}' on controller '{1}'", filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName, type.Name);
    }
}
```

You can apply this to exactly the actions you want or as what is called "[global action filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg618496)" if you want it to apply to all actions.

[More on filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513%28v=vs.98%29.aspx).